# Designing Objects for read only view

Tags: c#, oop

In my current project, I have a class Company that is composed of  other custom objects.

```
 class Company {
     Address mailingAddress;
     Address physicalAddress;
     MailingTypes mailinTypes; 
     ...
 }
```

When users search for companies, The UI has to display, Name, Address and Mailing Types.  I can get the data in either a DataSet or in a datareader. My question is, Do I have to create Company and child objects as I iterate over the results or should I create a new CompanyView Struct that just contains strings used to display as shown below?  Which is a better approach.

```
  class CompanyView {
      string MailingAddress;  
      string physicalAddress;
      ....
  }
```

Thanks,
Full Metal

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on the downstream usages of the results.  In some cases, it can be helpful to create a new object that is just strings for display only, especially if you have a large number of them to display.

But at the same time the other method would work as well.

Comment: We paginate and the maximum pageSize is 50. So not many objects.  So I would keep using my current Company object as is. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Override the ToString method on your Address class and you wont need to create a new CompanyView.

Comment: That is what my initial thought was. But to populate the company object, I'd have to be creating unnecesary Address objects. Is that the best practise.

Answer (score 0):

I am just working on a project that has similar functionality.  I am using something like:

```
class Company {
    Address _mailingAddress;
    [DisplayName("Mailing Address")]
    public string MailingAddress {
        get {
            if (_mailingAddress==null) {
                 return null;
            }
            return _mailingAddress.GetAdressString();
        }
    }
}
```

Class `Address` should have `GetAdressString()` method that should extract the address data in the appropriate form for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Address class  has a similar method to GetAddressString() and I'll be using that.

Comment: Np, I am using such method and am binding List<Company> (i your case) directly to datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

I would like my client code to look like this:

```
IAddress address = AddressFactory.MakeAddress("76 Main St", "3333", "CloseToNowhere");
Company c = Company.Make(address);
Console.WriteLine(c.MailingAddress.FullAddress);
```

And my back end code like this:

```
public interface IAddress
{
    string Steet { get; }
    string ZipCode { get; }
    string City { get; }
}

public interface IMailingAddress : IAddress
{
    string FullAddress { get; }
}

public static class AddressFactory
{
    private class Address : IAddress
    {
        public string Steet { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }

    private class MailingAddress : Address, IMailingAddress
    {
        public string FullAddress
            { get { return string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", Steet, ZipCode, City); } }
    }

    static public IAddress MakeAddress(string street, string zip, string city)
        { return new Address() { Steet = street, ZipCode = zip, City = city }; }

    static public IMailingAddress MakeMailingAddress(IAddress address)
        { return new MailingAddress() { Steet = address.Steet, ZipCode = address.ZipCode, City = address.City }; }
}


public class Company
{
    private IAddress _address;

    private Company(IAddress address) { _address = address; }

    static public Company Make(IAddress address)
        { return new Company(address); }

    public IAddress Address
        { get { return _address; } }

    public IMailingAddress MailingAddress
        { get{return AddressFactory.MakeMailingAddress(_address);} }

}
```